# How to spool query results in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I am trying to print query result. Here is the Oracle SQL Script:

```
set linesize 32767;
set pagesize 0; 
set newpage 0;
set space 0;
set echo off;
set feedback off;
set verify off;
set heading off;
set sqlprompt '';
set trimspool on;
set headsep off;

spool C:\asd.tmp
SELECT PROCESSNAME FROM ACTIVEPROCESSLIST ORDER BY PROCESSID;
spool off;
```

But the content of "asd.tmp" is that:

> SELECT PROCESSNAME FROM ACTIVEPROCESSLIST ORDER BY PROCESSID

It prints just query text, not the result of it. How can I spool query results?

NOTE: I am using "sqldeveloper-4.0.3.16.84-x64" and it runned as administrator. Also setting properties given above may be non-sense. I have tried some combinations of them and executing just spool commands without settings.

Any other solution that I can execute in C++ is proper for me too.

Comment: Does the query really return anything?

Comment: Yes, it returns 6  rows.

Comment: version 4.0.3 of SQL Developer is quite old and its support SQL\*Plus commands was not as robust as it is today. Go get version version 4.2 and try again - it's much closer to 100% SQL*Plus command/script engine support.  For example v4.0 doesn't support PAGESIZE 0.

Comment: I am not using my own computer. This computer belongs to my company and you know about company policies. I can not change the version of sqldeveloper. Also this query works same when I execute it in c++. I mean, it doesn't work in c++ too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an alternative way in [that link](https://community.oracle.com/thread/1063574). I recommend it. It doesn't work as fast as spool solution but it works in my project at least.

There was a problem about the alternative way but the answer in [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43120893/invalid-create-command-when-it-is-used-with-another-command) works fine. I am using it now.

Answer (score 0):

you can use command line/sqlplus. try save your script as a file, then in command line:

```
    sqlplus -s [username]/[password]@[sid] @file_path > output.txt
```

Comment: That works, I tried it. But it prints all data to the command line though my script file includes "set echo off" and it takes many time in big tables.