# Invalid CREATE command when it is used with another command

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, plsql

I am trying to print query result using solution in [that page](https://community.oracle.com/thread/1063574).  The spool solution didn't work in my project but the other one worked in sqldeveloper. "run_query" procedure defined in that page. The problem is that it doesn't work in c# code. The code is like that:

```
cmd.CommandText = string.Format(@"CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY TEST_DIR AS '{0}';
             exec run_query('SELECT {1} FROM  {2} {3} ORDER BY {4}','TEST_DIR','{5}');"
             ,strDirForFiles.Substring(0, strDirForFiles.Length - 2), 
             strColToSelect, strTableName, strWhere, strColToSelect, strTMPFileName);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

In runtime the query is like that:

```
CREATE DIRECTORY TEST_DIR AS 'C:\\';
exec run_query('SELECT AccountNumber 
                FROM  LowCreditList WHERE VersionNumber=1 AND ChangeStatus = 0 
                ORDER BY AccountNumber','TEST_DIR','ASD.TMP');
```

But that code throws an exception like that:

> Message = "ERROR [HY000] [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-00901: invalid CREATE
>   command\n"

When I execute just

```
CREATE DIRECTORY TEST_DIR AS 'C:\\';
```

command, there is no exception.

I can not figure it out. It works in sqldeveloper but not in C#.

NOTE: I use Visual Studio as administrator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know C# but I assume you can only send individual SQL statements or PL/SQL blocks, not a list separated by semicolons. In any case, `exec` is neither (it's a SQL*Plus shortcut supported by some IDEs.)

You probably need to send separate commands as something like:

```
create directory test_dir as 'C:\\'
```

and

```
begin run_query('SELECT {1} FROM  {2} {3} ORDER BY {4}','TEST_DIR','{5}'); end;
```

(Note PL/SQL uses semicolons but SQL has no native statement terminator, although tools often require a terminator character and semicolon is often the default.)